# Splitting cells along a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a table of data which looks like the following:

[image: Pre-processed data]

I need to go along the top row from cell E1, to the end of the data in the row, and split the headers into two. I'm hoping to get it to look something like this:

[image: Post-process data.]

I should mention, the headers change from "LZFmax_O 16Hz", to "LZFmin_O 16Hz" and so on, but all the headers have the "_O" before the frequency value, so i thought that this could used when it came to splitting the headers into two parts.

This is my first post here, and although I have experience with other coding languages, I'm very fresh with VBA.

Any help would be much appreciated, Cheers

Comment: Well I've already used a split function to separate values down a column, which looks like this:

Comment: Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    
    Dim tmpArray() As String
    
    With shtTempBBData
    
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If InStr(1, .Range("B" & i).Value, " ") Then
                tmpArray = Split(.Range("B" & i).Value, " ")
                .Range("B" & i).Value = tmpArray(0)
                .Range("C" & i).Value = tmpArray(1)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

Comment: But can't seem to get it to work for going along a row, rather than down a column

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1430925/edit) instead of adding information (and very hard to parse code) in comments

Comment: Apologies @cybernetic.nomad, still getting to know the forum etiquette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that might help you with some ideas:

```
 Sub delimit()
    Dim c As Range, arr As Variant, myRange As Range, lColumn As Long
        lColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set myRange = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, lColumn))
        For Each c In myRange
            arr = Split(c.Value, " ")
            If UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1 = 2 Then
                c.Value = arr(0)
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = arr(1)
            End If
        Next c
 End Sub
```

It's a combination of a split code I wrote yesterday and some stuff. 
So first we find the last column, then we set the range we want to go through.
I started my range on "`D1`" because it seemed to fit with the example data.

Then I loop through all the cells in that range, and run the Split.
If the Split returns the expected array with two values, we print them in the current cell and in the next cell.

This isn't very dynamic, and might overwrite stuff. Might want to put a condition in to not overwrite things by accidents. But I'm only trying to apply it to this specific scenario, and expect that we know all values that can appear.

It also only works if you run it in the right sheet, so if you want to change that then feel free.

Comment: Hi Christofer, this is what I thought would be the best way of doing it, but after changing the ActiveSheet to the sheet I want the code to apply to, nothing seems to happen? I've also tried putting it within a "With" loop but this doesn't seem to work either; any thoughts?

Comment: Never mind, I just used your code but selected the sheet I needed before, thanks so much!